# SWIFT: Get path only

Tags: swift, path, directory

I'm searching for a predefined function for getting the path from a path including filename. So instead of getting the filename I want the other part.

Of course I can do it like my own like:

```
func PathOnly() -> String {
    let n = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self).lastPathComponent?.characters.count
    return self.Left(self.characters.count - n!)
}
```

when extend String, but why reinvent the wheel? :-)
Any idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `NSString` method [`stringByDeletingLastPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/stringByDeletingLastPathComponent) and the `NSURL` method
[`URLByDeletingLastPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/URLByDeletingLastPathComponent) do exactly what you want.

Example:

```
let path = "/foo/bar/file.text"
let dir = (path as NSString).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
print(dir)
// Output: /foo/bar


let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/foo/bar/file.text")
let dirUrl = url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!
print(dirUrl.path!)
// Output: /foo/bar
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/foo/bar/file.text")
let dirUrl = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
print(dirUrl.path)
// Output: /foo/bar
```